# Laravel/Homestead - can't connect to the DB

Tags: database, laravel, homestead, sequelpro

I have installed homestead on my machine and cloned a project from a remote repository, now I am trying to create a DB for my project. 
This is how my .env file looks like:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:e7K7SUDgogNqTtP9TO1CfpbXFAC6FmLLSJ1l6K8pbWs=

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=localhost
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I have tried to connect to DB using sequel pro standard option:

```
Host: localhost
Password: secret
```

But I get:

> Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1, or the request timed out.
>
> Be sure that the address is correct and that you have the necessary
>   privileges, or try increasing the connection timeout (currently 10
>   seconds).
>
> MySQL said: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you set database connection properly? `DB_CONNECTION=mysql`. I don't see it in your .env file.

Comment: yes add your DB_CONNECTION and try this also DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

Comment: If you are using Mysql 8, I have answered this question here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51920183/connecting-to-sequel-pro-with-homestead-issues/64156476#64156476

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

- Check the service of mysql is running;
- Check the user and passowrd are correct;
- Check the privilege of the user, try `root` user

Answer (score 0):

For Mysql Connection you should have check username and password. and .env file

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=Your Database name
DB_USERNAME=username 
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Along With that, you can update database.php file for database configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the port `33060` to be able to connect. Hope that will help others who got stuck like me.

Answer (score 0):

I have some problem with Laravel 7 Homestead. I solve the error with this step:

1. Use mysql port 33060
2. Clear laraver config. `php artisan config:clear`
3. Reload vagrant `vagrant reload --provision`

And make sure your database name and password is correct.

Happy coding.