# Connecting to Sequel Pro with Homestead issues

Tags: laravel, homestead, sequelpro

I have been checking out a lot of answers here and on GitHub regarding this issue, but whatever I try there is always something wrong. I also don´t get why with the same credentials sometimes I am able to connect other times I am not even able to do that.

So right now I get the following error:

> "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   nodename nor servname provided, or not known

and I am not able to connect:

My .env credentials:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

My database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET'),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

...and for the standard connection, I use 192.168.10.10 for the host.

Comment: Are you created `homestead` database ? Or are you sure that, username or password is right ?

Comment: yes, the database it is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is with the `DB_HOST` parameter.  I included a full explanation.  Your fix is likely part of the final paragraph!

Laravel ships with a `.env.example` configured to connect to the Homestead MySQL out of the box.  Assuming you are running everything in Homestead, and Homestead is configured properly, you should be able to use the following database configuration to connect successfully.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

If you are trying to connect to the Homestead database from outside of Homestead, the Laravel documentation describes how you can do that as well.  You can check that out [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/homestead#connecting-to-databases).

Essentially what you need to do is connect to `127.0.0.1` as a host but use a different port (as opposed to `3306`.)  For MySQL, Homestead exposes a port `33060` that you should try to connect to instead.  For Sequel Pro this should fix your issue!

Answer (score 0):

**Updated October 2020**

If you are using MySql 8 there are some issues with that.

I was also not able to connect with the Laravel Homestead DB.
I solved the problem installing **Sequel Ace**, the successor of **SequelPro** which is available also on Mac AppStore.

https://github.com/Sequel-Ace/Sequel-Ace

Here a post from the SequelPro issues about:
https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/3705